# Consuming JSON request and producing different output

Tags: java, json, rest, restful-url

Can you point me to article or explain me how to declare RESTful web service which consumes JSON request and based on parameter inside JSON produces output in different formats, meaning customer can get output in JSON but in pdf also. I'm using Java and RestEasy on JBoss 5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the request on a method returning a RestEasy `Response` object, using a `ResponseBuilder` to build your response, setting dynamically the mime type of the response depending on a parameter in your JSON.

```
@POST
@Path("/foo")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response fooService(MyObject obj) {
   MyResponseEntity entity = MyObjectService.retrieveSomethingFrom(obj);
   return Response.status(200).entity(entity).type(obj.isXml() ? "text/xml" : "application/json").build();
}
```

This way if your `MyObject` domain object that represent incoming JSON has a parameter `xml` set to true, then the `Response` object is parameterized to produce `text/xml` otherwise it produces `application/json`. RestEasy should do the rest.

Comment: Service is called outside, client does not have reference to "MyObject". Would that be problem? How would he call this servic?

Comment: How is your service parsing the JSON into domain objects ? You said there was a parameter inside the JSON given to the service. If so, when the JSON is transformed into a Java Object, you have a getter on this property, so that you are able to decide what type of data you should produce (json, xml, whatever...).  Your client is sending JSON, so it's not a big problem.

Comment: I've got it, i am using Jackson as a provider to (de)serialize request into domain object..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
@Path("/")
public class Test {

@Path("/test")
@POST 
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response addOrderJSON(OrderDetails details) {...}


}
```